# Log-linear regression coefficient too small? Using R

Tags: regression-coefficients

I have a question.

I want to calculate a percent change in log(Earnings) if education or experience increases by 1 percent.
I tried it with the following regression in R:

```
Call:
lm(formula = exp(logearnings) ~ exp(experience + education), data = dat)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-838.34 -286.44  -51.88  207.21 2126.10 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       9.519e+02  1.347e+01  70.690   <2e-16 ***
exp(experience + education) 6.823e-13  3.023e-13   2.257   0.0243 *
```

It seems odd to me that the coefficients are so small.
So I wanted to ask you if I forgot something? I'm new to R and econometrics, sorry if I miss something obvious.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: are you sure you want the `exp` also on the explanatory variables?... also consider that the earnings might be in log format for a specific reason, maybe there is an exp relation between the explanatory variables and the response

Comment: Now that you mentioned it I might have misunderstood the lecture slide. But would you say that `lm(logearnings~experience + education)` would be an appropriate regression to show the effect on logearnings if education or experience changes by one percent?